# How to correctly define your 'company' Prelude

Tags: haskell

I have decided to use my own `Prelude` for a larger project (containing some libraries and some executables). The Prelude doesn't export some partial functions and exports some common functions (i.e. from `Control.Monad` etc.). However, I am fighting with the way how to do it. I have tried:

1. use `base-noprelude`. Create `Prelude.hs` in module `my-common-module`.
2. Same as above, but in the `my-common-module` create `My.Prelude` instead. In every other module create a directory 'prelude', put it into `hs-source-dirs` cabal section, create a file `prelude/Prelude.hs` with `import My.Prelude`

The problem is that in 1) I cannot just run `ghci`, as I get conflicting `base` and `my-common-module`. In 2) `ghci` works, `cabal repl` somehow doesn't as it fails mysteriously with 'attempting to use module ‘Prelude’ (prelude/Prelude.hs) which is not loaded'. Additionally, `base-noprelude` doesn't seem to like `ghcjs`, which I want to use for part of the project (code sharing).

It seems to me the only way currently is to start each and every file with:

```
import Prelude ()
import My.Prelude
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-} -- or extensions: NoImplicitPrelude in .cabal
...
import My.Prelude
```

The 'extensions: NoImplicitPrelude' option seems to me best as it requires every file to import `My.Prelude` otherwise it won't work. Am I missing some obvious way that would achieve custom Prelude and at the same time work with `cabal repl` and `ghcjs`?

Update: base-noprelude works with GHCJS when I manually remove the reexport of GHC.Event.

Update: Ok, I spent some time with this and I should have spent more. It seems to me that 1) is the right way to go. `cabal repl` works (thanks Yuras), ghci must be loaded with `ghci -hide-package base` and works too.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that (I tried hard). The issue with `attempting to use module ‘Prelude’` is reported [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10920).

Comment: Could you share a full example of 1) that works? Because it doesn't work for me :(
And I'm now sure where I helped your :)

Comment: I created a separate cabal project called `base-myprelude`. This defines some things and export `Prelude.hs` (I had to use some `NoImplicitPrelude` in some submodules as it tended to circle). Then I have my own project, 'my-project' that in the cabal depends on `base-noprelude, base-myprelude`. The project I'm working on isn't public, so I cannot point you to a repo. Update: `cabal repl` doesn't work in `base-myprelude`, but works in `my-project`, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Wow, moving prelude into a separate package is the key trick, thanks! You should post it as a real answer so that we can upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this setup that seems to work:

- Create a special package `my-prelude`. This package exports the `Prelude`, can contain other modules, it can depend on `base`. You may need to use `{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}` in some modules to avoid circular dependencies. E.g. you may want to have some orphan instances defined and exported by your custom `Prelude` in separate files (e.g. `Orphans.Lib_aeson`), these files need the `NoImplicitPrelude`.
- In your main project, libraries etc. change the dependencies in cabal from `base` to `base-noprelude, my-prelude`.

What works:

- `cabal repl`
- ghci/runghc works, but you have to start it with `ghci -hide-package base`; otherwise there will be conflict between `base` and `my-prelude`

What does not work:

- `cabal repl` in the `my-prelude` package.